# How can I get session data in PHP?

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I am new to PHP guys, so this is my problem

index.php

```
 if(!function_exists("session_register")) {  
    function session_register() {  
        $args = func_get_args();  
        if(count($args) <= 0)  
        return;  
        foreach($args as $key)  
            $_SESSION[$key] = $GLOBALS[$key];        
    }  
} 
include("connection2.php");
ob_start();
session_start();



if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {       
    
    $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['username']);     
    $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['pass']);     
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName='$myusername' and UserPassword='$mypassword'";   
    $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);   
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $userID = $row["UserID"];  
    $userType = $row["UserType"];  
    
    
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);             
    if($count >0 ) {
        if($userType == 2 || $userType == 1 ) { 
            $_SESSION['UserID']=$userID;
            $_SESSION['UserType']=$userType;
            header("location: dashboard.php");
            ob_end_flush();
            
        } else {
            
            
             header("location:index.php");
             ob_end_flush();
        }
    } 
}
```

session.php

```
<?php
   include('connection2.php');
   session_start();
   
   $userID =  $_SESSION['UserID'];
   $userType =  $_SESSION['UserType'];
   $ses_sql = mysqli_query($db,"select * from Users where UserID = $userid ");
   
   $row = mysqli_fetch_array($ses_sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
   
   $user_info = $row['UserInfo'];
   
   if(!isset($_SESSION['UserID'])){
      header("location:index.php");
      die();
   }
?>
```

dashboard.php

```
<?php 
include("session.php");

    if($userType == 1){
        include("_header.php");
    }else {
        include("_header2.php");
    }
    
   
?>
```

my code always redirects to index.php but i can see my variables  /* $userID = $row["UserID"];  */ and /* $userType = $row["UserType"];*/ in index.php

how can I pass my variables on dashboard.php with or without using session.

I need help. thank you very much.

Comment: `session_register()` has been removed long ago

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it through query param. So you can write,

```
header('location: dashboard.php?userId=' . $userID);
```

Then inside, `dashboard.php`, you can access the user's id by using `$_GET['userId']`.

Comment: no its not working for me. not include any _header

i pass userType but my URL like 

"http://x-x.com/dashboard.php?userType=%27%20.%201"